# Integrate .7z like .zip into windows explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, 7-zip

Is there a way to integrate .7z files like .zip files in Windows explorer. Where (like .zip) you double click the .7z file and the directory is opened in the explorer. Providing a password for encrypted archives.

Comment: FWIW I think the zip files support in Windows explorer is provided by Windows (Microsoft)...I can't say for sure that you can't extend Windows explorer yourself though.

Comment: I don't think Windows allows for that level of integration into Explorer.

Comment: Acronis True Image backup archives open in Windows Explorer when you double click them, so it seems to be possible for third-party software to extend Explorer functionality.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to integrate .7z into Windows Explorer.

Zip integration is implemented with build in Namespace Shell Extension. And 7z integration can be implemented with the same way. There are several known products allows you to integrate 7z into Explorer.

1) AlphaZip - http://www.alphazip.com/

Last update of Website was in 2013, and it looks like the product is abandoned.

2) ZipMagic - http://zipmagic.co/

Good solution but with minor problems. For example, I can not find the way to pack a file into subdirectory of archive.

3) TC4Shell - http://www.tc4shell.com/

Imho, the best solution. Full integration with Windows Explorer. It can use installed shell extension so you can see thumbnails of files inside archive, you can view file inside archive in the Preview Pane and so on. TC4Shell supports a lot of file types: zip, 7z, rar and many other.

Comment: for read access there's also this (free) compressed folder shell extension https://www.zabkat.com/blog/compressed-folder-shell-extension.htm

Answer (score 1):

"qiewer extractor" can open .7z in the explorer like as .zip.

qiewer extractor - https://sourceforge.net/projects/qiewer-extractor/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I cannot delete an archive which I visited with this tool turned on.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. At least, not without 3rd party tools anyway.

The .ZIP functionality that Windows provides is actually a .DLL that is tied into Explorer.  When you look at a .ZIP file's contents, you are executing an application for handling .zip files that happens to look and smell just like an Explorer window, but it's actually not Explorer at all.  The reason the two integrate so well is because Microsoft wrote both components.

7-Zip, on the other hand, is a 3rd party tool.  It has a registry entry into Explorer (which is why you get the context menus).  It even works the same way when you double-click the file, but instead of launching a .zip handler that Microsoft wrote, it launches a .7z handler that 7-Zip wrote.

Technically there is a slight difference between the two.  Microsoft's handler is entirely a .DLL whereas 7-Zip is an .EXE.  But what you are in effect asking is why can't 7-Zip look more like Microsoft.  And the answer to that is because they didn't want or care to.

Comment: Zip Folders (later, Ontrack Zip Magic) was integrating in Explorer very well. One even could run a game from inside a zip archive.

Comment: @Anixx lol no.  if you were to open a zip file and executed a game, it was extracted to a temporary file and folder.

Comment: @Keltari: Those "Zip Folders" integration were no different from current Windows Explorer integration for .ZIP file: both are extracting to %TEMP% before running the application.

Comment: @AntoineL it was different, it used a driver. Now you can run a multi-file game from a .zip file.